# Sprints section shows tasks as unparented

Tags: azure-devops

I am not sure if this has been answered before, I have looked all over Google and can't seem to find any real answer. Apparently Microsoft allows you to view parent items to tasks in the Sprints section, and I've seen this done at my workplace when we view the Taskboard.

In my own personal DevOps configuration, I've made a custom work item type called "Goal", and assigned "Task" items as children to these "Goals". However, when viewing the Taskboard, all of my tasks show as "Unparented". My goals and tasks are on the same area path and iteration path.

[image: Task has one parent item as a Goal] [image: Taskboard not showing goals]

In my Backlog levels settings, I've created a top level portfolio backlog named "Goals" that only uses the "Goals" work item type. When I change the Iteration backlog to include "Goal" work items, it puts the work item type on the same iteration as "Task" work items, and the Taskboard does not properly populate.

[image: Goal backlog level]

Is there something I'm missing? I've tried to read multiple documentation pages on Microsoft's website to no avail.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/resolve-backlog-reorder-issues?view=azure-devops

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/set-up-your-backlog?view=azure-devops#taskboard-types

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/select-backlog-navigation-levels?view=azure-devops

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/organize-backlog?view=azure-devops

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#add-or-edit-portfolio-backlogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to contact DevOps Support and get an answer. The issue was that I could only create Portfolio Backlogs, not Requirement Backlogs. By changing the default Requirement Backlog to include my custom work item, those showed in the Sprints section.